# Unity3D - Gap between two cubes

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity3d, I dragged two cubes next together but when hit play they have a gap like the picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's because they are two different objects. Unity is not a modeling tool. Use a 3D model to model your object in once piece then import into Unity

Comment: It also could be Z-fighting when stacking objects on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold the V key to activate the vertex snapping mode.
Do this in the unity editor when moving the cubes to ensure they are exactly aligned.

Answer (score -1):

As it was mentioned, seam between objects appear because there is two different objects which are has no common relations (vertices i.e.). 
If you want some modeling or level design right inside Unity it's a good idea to use tools such as ProBuilder which is part of Unity now. In a few words, ProBuilder provide support of creating and editing 3d objects inside Unity and many other related things.

Check out video for quick view:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kjqx6cKUepc

Also, you can check out some tutorials:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@4.0/manual/index.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22247474)

Comment: There is no certain solution for the issue, so answer is going to help to find right direction according to what he wants to achieve.
Anyway, I will add some details.